Replying to an editor after plagiarism accusation and manuscript rejection
As the title of this question suggests, a manuscript that I submitted was flagged as plagiarized by iThenticate and was rejected by the editor.
The editor claims that the manuscript has 35% similarity with a previous manuscript that I submitted to the same journal. The email made me feel very bad, as the accusations are something that I have intentionally avoided throughout my publications. I also should note that I chose not to write repeated information and instead wrote a summary of some of the methods while citing the mentioned already published work.
Summary about the scope: it's mainly about sensors and machine learning, though both papers have very different goals and methodologies:

Already published work: usage of many sensors to achieve two goals
with machine learning regression and classification.
Submitted manuscript: usage of one sensor to achieve a completely
different goal from the already published work by machine learning
classification and to explain the models with explainable machine
learning.

We do not have access to iThenticate, but we do have access to Turnitin. The summary:

Overall, there is 23% similarity with other published work.
With the paper that the editor mentioned, there is only 8%
similarity.
The similarity mainly comes from affiliations, references, acknowledgments (funding agency and project number).
The description of the sensor is flagged as well (name of sensor,
company, location).

I have no idea how to do the following:

To tell my mentors that this happened; I'm afraid that I will be in
trouble if I do not sufficiently rebut the plagiarism accusation.
To write to the editor to clarify what happened, though I suspect
they already checked where the similarity is coming from.


What is your position? PhD, post Doc, or what?

I am currently finishing up my PhD, this was suposed to be the last publication (5th) @Walter

@DanielHatton I have checked the other overlaps as well, it was mainly technical terms such as Machine Learning, units, sensor name and name of manufacturer. There are also very generic overlaps such as "samples were taken" or "frequency spectra". I did not copy paste anything except for some parts of the methods section where I also rephrased and added a source to previously published work.

@DanielHatton the editor mentions "... , the overlap goes beyond the normal occurrence of standard phrases in your field... Text copied from copyrighted works from third parties, even in an introduction, should never be used without clearly identifying the other source. Every manuscript should present some new results or insights and be written in an author's own words....". I tried to reproduce the problem with turnitin, but could not. Most overlap comes from the already mentioned sources: references, technical terms, affiliations, funding agency, etc...

@DanielHatton here I should also mention that I opened both manuscripts side-by-side. Could not determine any similarities other than the ones that I already mentioned.

The editor doesn't seem to be aware that you are the author of both papers. Otherwise why does he talk about third parties? It would be worth pointing that out to him, but I would certainly look elsewhere for publication.

@DanielHatton yes, still in the same publishing house

@user207421 the editor mentioned that the overlap is with a previously published work by the same authors.

(Nitpick: you probably don't mean rebuke here.  Perhaps rebut?)

@gidds yeah, sorry for the semantic typo. Not a native english speaker...

@TinoD No need to apologise — native speakers often misuse those words, too.  But perhaps you could edit the question so we can see exactly what you meant?

@TinoD In that case the question of plagiarism does not arise. You can’t plagiarize from yourself, by definition. Did he really use that word?

@user207421 after an email to the publishing house, they sent me a reply that "we see the editor took the following decision reject - plagiarism". Although in the comments he only wrote "high similarity" and that the work is not "original due to the high similarity". I think he didn't look at where the similarity is coming from. Still no reply from him


The role of a mentor is to support you, not to punish you. So, IMHO you should/could have asked this very question to them. They presumably have some experience with this journal and can provide better advise then we can here (as we don't know the journal).
I suspect the editor has not carefully checked where the 35% similarity comes from, since your own analysis doesn't show undue similarities. I would write to the editor pointing our the similarities you are aware of and which are perfectly fine (affiliation, grant number, sensor make etc). If the editor rejects your arguments without really answering them, then I would consider a different editor or journal. There is no point in dealing with editors that see no sense.


thanks for the answer, I will discuss this with the supervisor as you mentioned.

+1. With respect to OP's question about writing to the editor, I would foot-stomp the advice here: talk to your supervisor before replying at all. Your supervisor can certainly give advice about how to phrase your reply -- or they may be so outraged that they send a strongly-worded reply in their own name. Either way, better to coordinate your strategies.

What if the journal has a policy of flagging authors for plagiarism and preventing them from submitting other papers? It's not clear if that's the case here, but if it is, and it's an important journal in the field, it may be worth fighting just to ensure they can submit other papers in the future.

@anjama i'm afraid this can happen. At the end of the comments from the editor: "... the journal will automatically detect the repeated submisison of this paper, and maybe reject it."

@TinoD I think it's pretty standard that you can't resubmit a rejected paper (unless invited to do so). I'm referring to hypothetical future papers that are different from the one that was rejected

@anjama Is that a policy that exists in any journal?

I agree that it is important to wipe that stain off even if one does not intended to resubmit to the journal. If only for the record.

@AzorAhai-him- DNA and Cell Biology announced 3-year bans for evidence of misconduct (plagiarism, data manipulation, etc) back in 2015. No idea if it's still an active policy (I don't see it in current author guidelines, but it may still be an internal policy)

Anecdotal answer here. I once had a similar experience, except it was 98% similarity...to the preprint of that paper on biorxiv. Never assume editors have put in the leg work, they have a lot on their plates and do it without pay. I politely pointed this out to them, I got an apology, it progressed and was published.

Thank you for your answer! I brought a paper back to life once before: editor rejected despite the positive reviews. I wrote the editor and they mentioned a "mistake occured during the decision process". The decision was rescinded and now it is still in revision...
